# Radio Buttons Showing a Value of 0 in mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

My radio buttons have values of "1", "2", "3" and my database is set up to receive the values as INT's.  However, when the form is submitted they come into the database as zeros in each field.  Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSwL8/)

```
<p><input type="radio"  name="buttons"  value="1">A-Flat
```

// I already have my database connected

```
// variables
$frets =  $_POST["fret"]; 
$fonts =  $_POST["fonts"]; 
$buttons =  $_POST["buttons"];


// if else to display the results
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // mysql

    $query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (frets, fonts, buttons) VALUES ('$frets','$fonts','$buttons') ";
mysql_query ($query);

mysql_close();  

    // stuff
    echo '<h1>Thanks!!</h1>','<p>',"I lied about the prize. Here is a funny video to make up for it.",'</p>','<br />',
        '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3-HCs4tRw8o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}

 else {

    // page header
    echo '<h1>', "You broke it!",'</h1> ';

    // message
    echo '<h3 style=text-align:center;>',"Silly Rabbit! Make sure you fill out all the fields!", "<br>",
             "<a href=usertesting.php>Try again.</a>",'</h3>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: echo $query just before you execute mysql_query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.echo the value of `$buttons`, ie `echo $buttons;` and see what is coming there.

2.Change query to :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (frets, fonts, buttons) VALUES ('".$frets."','".$fonts."','".$buttons."') ";
mysql_query ($query);
```

3. Also check the data type of `buttons` in your DB

Your query is prone to sql injection, Make it seccure.

mysql_* functions are deprected use mysqli_* functions OR PDO

Comment: +! for use mysqli_* functions OR PDO

Comment: Why would you change the query to your example?

Comment: @shapeshifter : I added concatenation to separate variables from other string, It may not affect the current problem but it is always better to do so.

Comment: Why?  There is almost no performance benefit and double quoted strings are alot better for legibility.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  When I echo $buttons I'm not getting anything.  Here is the jsFiddle with the php in the javascript window: http://jsfiddle.net/VSwL8/

Comment: Try print_r($_POST); and see if any thing is coming there

Comment: In  jsFiddle you dont have a starting form tag, Do you really have a form tag in your real code ?

Comment: It says, "Array ( [submit] => then the Submit button text )"

Comment: ohhh...So you are not getting any form values, I guess problem is with your form....Can you paste your form here

Comment: I'm a frickin idiot.  It was the form tag. It is working now. Thanks so much @PrasanthBendra

Comment: @Prasanth Bendra still wondering why its 'always better to' concatenate strings.  Did you just make this up?